# How to fit a long equation in a beamer frame with multiple columns

Tags: beamer, equations

How to get the following frame in `beamer`:

[image]

I am using the following code:

```
\begin{frame}{}
        %\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{
        \hspace{-1.2cm}
        \begin{adjustbox}{width=1.1\textwidth}
            \renewcommand\arraystretch{1.3}
            \begin{tabularx}{1.1\textwidth}{X | X| X}%\vrule width 1.5pt

                \tiny \colorbox{lilad!15}{title1}                  &
                \tiny \colorbox{lilad!15}{title2}   &
                \tiny \colorbox{lilad!15}{ title3}            \tabularnewline 
                \textbullet\ a                           & 
                \textbullet\ d                                                   & 
                \textbullet\   f                                                                       \tabularnewline 
                \textbullet\ b                    & 
                               t                                                                              & 
                                                                                   \tabularnewline
                \textbullet\ c                                     & 
                \textbullet\ e                                                    & 
                \textbullet\    e                                                    \tabularnewline
                $ D_{j}=\sqrt{\left | \left (\Delta P_{50th} -P_{50} \right )^{2} \right |- \left | \left (\Delta T_{50th} -T_{50} \right )^{2}  \right |}$     & 
                                                                                                   &   \tabularnewline                                
                &  
                                                                    &  
                                                                \tabularnewline

                &  
                $\displaystyle\begin{multlined}[t][0.1\hsize]   f_{5,j}=  1 -\left ( \frac{\left |\sigma_{CMj}   -\sigma_{Obs} \right | }{2\sigma_{Obs}} \right )^{0.5}   \\    f_{4,j}=  1 -\left ( \frac{\left |\overline{A_{CMj}}   -\overline{A_{Obs}} \right | }{2\overline{A_{Obs}}} \right )^{0.5}       \\f_{1,j}= 1-\left ( \frac{\left | A_{CMj} - A_{Obs}\right | }{2A_{Obs}}   \right ) ^{0.5}\\f_{1,j}= 1-\left ( \frac{\left | A_{CMj} - A_{Obs}\right | }{2A_{Obs}}   \right ) ^{0.5}]\end{multlined}$  
                &  
    \end{tabularx}
        \end{adjustbox}

        \end{frame}
```

I can not fix the long equation. Does anybody know, how to get that structure?

This is the output I am getting with the above code:
[image]

Comment: Please make your example compilable. Which beamer themes do you use?

Comment: I am using  \usetheme{Frankfurt}.

Comment: Unless you make the font size extremely small, I don't think you will fit all the equations into this three column layout.

Answer (score 1):

Probably `tabularx` is not the proper tool to achieve this, when you have `columns` in beamer.
Besides that, try to give all the elements required to reproduce your problem (what color is `lilad`?).

I replaced the `tabularx` with the `columns` environment.

The equations were resized to fit in the columns with `\resizebox`, and I also changed `multlined` with `gathered` for a nicer alignment.

```
\documentclass[options]{beamer}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usetheme{Frankfurt}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{}
    \begin{columns}[t]
        \begin{column}{0.33\textwidth}
            \begin{center}
                \tiny \colorbox{red!15}{title1}
            \end{center}
            \begin{itemize}
                \item a
                \item b
                \item c
            \end{itemize}
            \resizebox{\columnwidth}{!}{$\displaystyle   D_{j}=\sqrt{\left | \left (\Delta P_{50th} -P_{50} \right )^{2} \right |- \left | \left (\Delta T_{50th} -T_{50} \right )^{2}  \right |}$}
        \end{column}
        \vrule{}
        \begin{column}{0.33\textwidth}
            \begin{center}
                \tiny \colorbox{red!15}{title2}
            \end{center}
            \begin{itemize}
                \item d
                \item t
                \item e
            \end{itemize}
            \resizebox{\columnwidth}{!}{$\displaystyle%
                \begin{gathered}
                    f_{5,j} =  1 -\left ( \frac{\left |\sigma_{CMj}   -\sigma_{Obs} \right | }{2\sigma_{Obs}} \right )^{0.5} \\
                    f_{4,j} =  1 -\left ( \frac{\left |\overline{A_{CMj}}  - \overline{A_{Obs}} \right | }{2\overline{A_{Obs}}} \right )^{0.5} \\
                    f_{1,j} = 1-\left ( \frac{\left | A_{CMj} - A_{Obs}\right | }{2A_{Obs}}   \right ) ^{0.5} \\
                    f_{1,j} = 1-\left ( \frac{\left | A_{CMj} - A_{Obs}\right | }{2A_{Obs}}   \right ) ^{0.5}
                \end{gathered}%
            $}
        \end{column}
        \vrule{}
        \begin{column}{0.33\textwidth}
            \begin{center}
                \tiny \colorbox{red!15}{title3}
            \end{center}
            \begin{itemize}
                \item f
                \item e
                \item Continuous
            \end{itemize}
        \end{column}
    \end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]